# ImageView size valid only in onGlobalLayout()

Tags: java, android, imageview, size, oncreate

I have a problem with getting the size of ImageView in an android app I'm making. I've read several solutions to this problem and none of them seem to solve my problem. I just want to get the size once at the beginning of the application like in onCreate() before loading anything to the ImageView (When it's empty.) and use it for the rest of my app.

The solution that almost works is the one with getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener.
I did that and it is getting me the right size and everything but only in the onGlobalLayout() method. All I want to do is to save that size in some class global variable but everything that happens in onGlobalLayout() stays there. It's like it has no effect on the rest of the class. I can't really write my whole application in that method it's ridiculous. Why is it happening and how can I fix that?

Also I tried the OnFocusChangeListener solution and it gives me the size only if I try to exit the app. As expected the focus is changed but this is not what I need.

Here is the code:

```
public class Fractaler extends Activity {

int finalWidth;
int finalHeight;
TextView txt;
ImageView fractal;
Fractal mandelbrot;
boolean viewIsMeasured = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {

    txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt);
    fractal = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.mainImage);
    fractal.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            if (!viewIsMeasured) {
                finalWidth=fractal.getWidth();
                finalHeight=fractal.getHeight();
                viewIsMeasured = true;
                mandelbrot=new Fractal("Mandelbrot",finalWidth,finalHeight);
                fractal.setImageBitmap(mandelbrot.create());
            }
        }


    });

    txt.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
    //txt.setText(String.valueOf(mandelbrot.getWidth())+"    "+String.valueOf(mandelbrot.getHeight()));


}



@Override
protected void onStart() {

    super.onStart();


}
```

}

Comment: you have to add addOnGlobalLayoutListener with your view . 
because in oncreate view is not rendered yet so its giving width and height as 0

Comment: *I can't really write my whole application in that method* - so, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you need full control over the size & appearance of a view, a custom `View` would really be the way to go.

Comment: It didn't help the same problem with custom view. I want to get the size in which I can generate my images into. It depends on the screen size and how the view is fitting to the screen size. The only thing that allowed me to do it is to get it onWindoFocusChanged() but it requires to minimize the app and run it again how come something that simple can be so hard to achieve?

Comment: Found a different solution:                                    final class Fractal extends ImageView {

 DisplayMetrics size;

 public Fractal(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {

  super(context, attrs, defStyle);

  size = this.getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();

  width = size.widthPixels;
  height = size.heightPixels;